# How to route android streamed audio to google glass via Bluetooth

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

Yes, I would have liked to use A2DP but, during the initial research we discovered that glass didn't support that profile. And so I considered the possibility of using HSP to relay the audio, however i ran into a few issues while doing so.

- I was trying to use bluetooth SCO and then setting the stream type to STREAM_VOICE_CALL, in hopes that it would define the profile.

  The code reference used was:

  ```
  localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  localAudioManager.setMode(0); 
  localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true); 
  localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco(); 
  localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
  ```

However this did not help. I tried playing around with this code, setting different stream types, but in all cases, the audio was not being routed to the glass headset.

- Is there some other way to force the audio onto the HSP profile?
- Could you guide me with some code reference to achieve our objective?

NB: I have a bluetooth socket open at all times between glass and the tablet application. Could this possibly have an adverse effect on routing the audio to glass over the HSP profile?